# How to invoke a .bat file and send a String using ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I need to be able to achieve following in my Java project-
    1) Invoke a .bat file using ProcessBuilder class
    2) send command to that subprocess (.bat application) using Process.getOutPutStream()

I am able to achieve the 1st part, but unable to achieve the 2nd part

So the idea is to open a bat file(oddJobTest.bat)  which is another Java program on my local, and send some specific commands to that. This java application actually contains some Switch Case logic that i can only trigger if i could pass the specific String/commands.
for e.g- 
- If i pass "bac", then do Begin Transation Logic
- If i pass "eac", then do End Transaction logic

```
CoreCashMqttClient.connect();
File oddJobTest = new File("C:/spool/oddjob/build/distributions/oddjob- 
0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/oddjob-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/bin");
    //Use of"/K" makes sure that the OddJob.bat remains active.
ProcessBuilder pbOddJob = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/K", 
"Start","oddjobTest.bat");      
    pbOddJob.directory(oddJobTest);             
    try {
        p = pbOddJob.start();

        System.out.println(p.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    String payload = ""; // pass some data
    CoreCashMqttClient.publish(payload);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    try {
        writer.write("bac");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With the below code- i am expecting that the command line that opened as a SubProcess should receive "bac" as a String

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
writer.write("bac");
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `ProcessBuilder pbOddJob = new ProcessBuilder("oddjobTest.bat");`?

Comment: I get this error- java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "oddjobTest.bat" (in directory "C:\spool\oddjob\build\distributions\oddjob-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT\oddjob-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Ok, make sure that the working `directory` is set to the same location that `oddjobTest.bat` is stored

Comment: with working directory do you mean "pbOddJob.directory(oddJobTest)" this? Here oddJobTest is pointing to the location where oddJobTest.bat file is stored.

Comment: Yes, and I'd make sure that the file exists in said directory - don't assume

Comment: sure, thanks for the suggestion. I have the file existing in that location. As the 
    ProcessBuilder pbOddJob = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/K", 
    "Start","oddjobTest.bat"); is working just fine, only issue is in sending the command "bac" to it after the bat file has launhed.

Comment: Well, to answer that, we'd need to know how the bat file is accepting input